# Print out a string at a specific coordinate, c# Console Application

Tags: c#, string, printing

I want to create a program that prints out a string at any given coordinates. I have a main class and a class i created called ConsoleText. Here are the code for each class:

```
class ConsoleText
{
    public int x, y; // Coordinates
    public string Text = "Hello!";
    ConsoleColor color;

    public ConsoleText(int x, int y, string Text)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = color;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        Console.Write(Text);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```

and here is the program(main) class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleText obj = new ConsoleText(19, 1, "Hello!");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

My problem now is that when I debug the program, I get the positions for the coordinate but the string dosen´t write out at that specific coordinate. Any ideas on what i might have done wrong?

Comment: Your cursor position calculation appears to be off. I base this on what I read in MSDN on Console.SetCursorPosition. Console.Clear() zero's the origin, then they fetch the absolute origin using ConsoleCursor.Top and ConsoleCursor.Left. Finally, the x & y values are added to saved values of ConsoleCursor.Left and ConsoleCursor.Top.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works perfectly for me:

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 0);
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 2);
Console.WriteLine("World");
Console.ReadLine();
```

You might want to explore WHY you want to use a custom class at all.

EDIT: Also, the values for x and y in the ConsoleObj class are never referred to.  Just pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = color;
```

to this:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
```

You were inadvertently setting the foreground color to black.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SetCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx) API doc's in MSDN. Apparently, the cursor position has to be set relative. Use Console.Clear() to reset cursor position, then fetch the top,left. The API Doc's show how to do this.

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(x + ConsoleCursor.Left, y + ConsoleCursor.Top);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you're trying to print the *message* and *coordinate* at the same time.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConsoleText(19, 1, "Hello!");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public static void ConsoleText(int x, int y, string Text)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        Console.Write(string.Format("x:{0}, y:{1}, message:{2}", x, y, Text));
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
```